# Get latest frame from camera using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am using opencv 3.0 to capture frames from video camera. But processing the frame takes some time, so the next time I fetch a frame, it gives me an older frame. I want to capture always the last frame, how can I do this?`capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` gives me error.

Answer (score -1):

please try to call "capture >> MatImage" OR "capture.read(MatImage)" statement a twice in same function.